# why I cannot shift the floating element along the specified axes in order to keep it in view in my case?

Tags: react-tsx

`import { shift, useFloating, } from '@floating-ui/react'

const App = () => {
const { x, y, strategy, refs } = useFloating({ middleware: [shift({ mainAxis: true, crossAxis: true })] })
return (
<div style={{ backgroundColor: "black", width: '2000px', height: '2000px' }}>
<div ref={refs.setReference} style={{ backgroundColor: "orange", width: "max-content" }}>
reference element

<div ref={refs.setFloating} style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", width: "max-content", position: strategy, top: y ?? 0, left: x ?? 0 }}>
A floating element that shifts along the x-axis


)
}
export default App`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBs4e.png)

I want to fix this issue